# Which framework is better apache cordova and ionic framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

My requirement is to display data from API and user logging facility and that is to be released in all the platform

- iOs
- Android
- Windows

Problem is;

I was searching for a better framework adopt all these i have got choices like

- Apache Cordova
- IONIC

I need to know which will be most comfortable for

- Design
- API Consumption
- Rapid Development

I have referred some blog and videos about both of frameworks and kindly give me a small overview and suggestion towards what to proceed with?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: ionic framework uses cordova

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic is built on top on Cordova.
I would personally recommend Ionic for any type of rapid development and native looking mobile applications.

Comment: thanks man i have got a clear view after both of your answers

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite tough to answer and depends totally on choice.

First Ionic is built on top of Cordova's Command line functionality and Angular's MVC Architecture.

Using Cordova you don't really have any constraint on how to build an HTML app.

But because Ionic is built on top of Angular, it inherits all of Angular's goodies and has to follow the structure of an Angular app.

As I said it come down to a choice of how you wish to build you app.